# Java: Is there a reason why multiple references to the same object would fail to update when contained in a hashmap?

Tags: java, reference, hashmap

This was an attempt to answer a daily challenge on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/june-leetcoding-challenge-2021/603/week-1-june-1st-june-7th/3769/). The link to the problem is here. You can run the code to see what happens

My attempt at an O(n) solution involved adding all the numbers to a hashmap with the run length as the value, and new entries would get the object reference from it's pre-existing neighbours. If an entry would fall between two different consecutive runs it would simply replace the value reference of one with the other. However, the merge doesn't work as expected. I've identified the misbehaviour below.

val1 refers to the run greater than, and val2 is the run lesser than. I've had to contain the Integer object in two layers of arrays to get the referencing to work as intended (integer objects seem to assign by value and not by object reference). The code as it is now works up until test case 66. Doing the assignment the other way fails at test case 40-something. The reference getting incremented in problem line 1 stays synced across all the numbers in it's consecutive run as expected, but the reference getting reassigned in line 2 only seems to update the one entry adjacent to the current number, and at the other end of its run the Integer reference remains pointing to the old value for some reason, despite the fact that they should all be pointing to the same nested array.

This is how I imagine what's happening in the hashmap in the problem example. (They're supposed to all be pointing to the 9 after the merge.)

before
. . .[[4]] . . . . . . . . . . . [[4]]
. .___|___ . . . . . . . . . . . _|_
/ . . . . . . \ . . . . . . . . ./ . . . .\ 
-6 -5 -4 -3 . . -2 . . -1 0 1 2
. . . . . . . . .| . . . .| . . . .|
. . . . . . . . .| . . . .| . . val 1
. . . . . . .val2 . . new key

after?
. . . . . . . [[9]] . . . . . . . . .[[4]]
. .________|________ . . . . . |
/ . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . \ . . /. .\  
-6 -5 -4 -3 . . -2 . . -1 0 1 2
. . . . . . . . .| . . . .| . . . .|
. . . . . . . . .| . . . .| . . val 1
. . . . . . .val2 . . new key

Is there any reason why multiple references to the same object should desynchronize in a hash map?

```
class Solution {
    public int longestConsecutive(int[] nums) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer[][]> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int num : nums) {
            if (!map.containsKey(num)) {
                Integer[][] val1 = map.get(num+1);
                Integer[][] val2 = map.get(num-1);
                if (val1 == null && val2 == null) {
                    map.put(num, new Integer[][] {new Integer[] {1}});
                    System.out.println(num + " " + map.get(num)[0]);
                } else if (val1 != null && val2 != null) { //problem clause
                    System.out.print(num + " val1: " + val1[0] + " val2: " + val2[0]);
                    val2[0][0] += val1[0][0] + 1; // line 1
                    val1[0] = val2[0]; // line 2
                    map.put(num, val2);
                    System.out.println("  new val1: " + val1[0] + "  new val2: " + val2[0]);
                } else if (val1 != null) {
                    System.out.print(num + " val1: " + val1[0]);
                    val1[0][0] += 1;
                    map.put(num, val1);
                    System.out.println("  new val1: " + val1[0]);
                } else if (val2 != null) {
                    System.out.print(num + " val2: " + val2[0]);
                    val2[0][0] += 1;
                    map.put(num, val2);
                    System.out.println("  new val2: " + val2[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        Iterator<Integer[][]> it = map.values().iterator();
        int max = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            int temp = it.next()[0][0];
            max = Math.max(max, temp);
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any hash based collection demands that for a given input key, the hash be consistent.  And if the key is the same, which value should be returned?  If you want a multi hash map, refer to Google collections library.

Comment: The key's are not the problem, it's the values. The values are meant to be references to external Integer objects (through two layers of containing arrays) so that when the Integer value is updated, it is reflected in all the entries pointing to it. I don't think you've understood my question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to implement a [Union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) structure but implementing it like this can't work.

The problem is that if you have a set of `{a, b, c, d}`. Then you can merge `a` and `b`, and then `c` and `d` with a single assignment. But when you try to merge the combined values of `{a,b}` with `{c,d}` then using one assignment can't change the values of all of the original elements. That would require 3 total assignments to change the values of 4 values.

Adding extra arrays doesn't change anything because you still need to change which array every element is referring to which has the same problem. It's as if you were doing:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;

a = b;
c = d;
b = c;

System.out.println(a+","+b+","+c+","+d); // [2,4,4,4]
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I think I see the problem now. I assumed I had fixed that exact issue but evidently I was mistaken. The keys of the two seperate runs still point to different references after the merge attempt which is never fixed, and to do so would make it O(n^2) time complexity.